# How do you use the changing of variable formula to solve this problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you express the area(express both respectively in integral) bounded by the following curves (i.e. the shape with one side corresponding to one curve):
$$xy=1, \quad xy^2=3,\quad x^2-y^2=26,\quad x^2-y^3=11$$

By using changing of variable formula to express those area into a integral with 4 different variable, that is, mapping the curves into another plane(when you parametrize one curve you with get one number, you get 4 different number in total with four curves)

I know you may think this question may be the duplicate of that question, but that question only ask for using only one variable integral:

[How do we calculate the area of a region bounded by four different curves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95104/how-do-we-calculate-the-area-of-a-region-bounded-by-four-different-curves)

i know the change of variable formula only work up to 3-dimentional, so does changing of the variable formula help to solving my problem?

Comment: @Victor: Is there any reason to think that a helpful change of variables exists? It is very fine for you to go and experiment with this toy - you will learn a lot! One of the things you are about to learn concerns the limitations of the technique.

Comment: Can you provide a plot?

Comment: @Victor I would have to agree with Jyrki that there really isn't any reason to think there is a "nice" change of variables for this problem. But there is a more fundamental issue at hand, what region are you referring to? [Here is a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+xy%3D1%2C+xy%5E2%3D3%2C+x%5E2%E2%88%92y%5E2%3D26%2C+x%5E2%E2%88%92y%5E3%3D11+where+x%3D2.5+to+6.5) of these curves. You can see several regions which are bound by them. Which region are you looking to find the area of?

Comment: @BillCook- how to find both respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you wrote

$$
xy=1, \quad xy=3,\quad x^2-y^2=26,\quad x^2-y^2=11 \ ,
$$

the answer would be easier: you could use the following change of variables

$$
u = xy, \quad v = x^2 - y^2 \ .
$$

Then your area would be

$$
\iint_D dxdy = \int_1^3 \int_{11}^{26}\vert JT(u,v) \vert dvdu  \ ,
$$

where $D$ is the area enclosed by the curves, and $JT(u,v)$ the jacobian of the change of coordinates $(x,y) = T(u,v)$. Unfortunately, this is the inverse of the change of variables you actually know. Namely,

$$
(u,v) = T^{-1}(x,y) = (xy, x^2 - y^2) \ ,
$$

but you could resort to the fact that

$$
JT(u,v) = JT(x,y)^{-1}\circ T(u,v) = \frac{-1}{2(x^2+y^2)\circ T(u,v)}  \ .
$$

Still, that $T(u,v)$ insists to appear. So, in fact, this kind of exercise usually goes like this: compute

$$
\iint_D (x^2+y^2)dxdy \ .
$$

In this situation, you cancel out both $(x^2 + y^2)\circ T(u,v)$ and you're happy as a clam:

$$
\iint_D (x^2+y^2)dxdy = \int_1^3 \int_{11}^{26} ((x^2 + y^2)\circ T(u,v)) \frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)\circ T(u,v)}dvdu = \frac{1}{2} \int_1^3 \int_{11}^{26} dvdu \ .
$$

So, it's just usually a prefabricated exercise in order to practise the change of variables and the Jacobian of the inverse function.

Comment: i need a answer that match with my original problem

Comment: Well, good luck looking for it.